# My hologram looks great in preview but when I render it, it looks bad

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, materials, 3d-view

You'll see... I'm creating a small mod for a video game and, among other things, I've taken one of the original models to introduce it with a hologram appearance at a specific moment, and the result looks very good to me during the preview...

[image]

But after rendering (I render it in PNG images) look how it looks like...

[image]

All the internal and external bloom effect seems to have disappeared and only the contour lines are observed. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

i believe the thing that makes you think the render look great is the **"bloom"** feature in eevee.
.

if you are rendering in cycles, you will not have **"bloom"** unless you add a **glare node** in the compositing tab.

[image]

or

if you are rendering in eevee, and the output not showing the **"bloom"**, its because you are rendering in transparent png, which the alpha of the image cut s out the **bloom**. so the solution is render with a background, don't render with transparent on.
[image]

this setting
[image]

or

the most proper way is, render in eevee/ cycles and you will not see any **bloom**, and give the **"glow" or "bloom"** in other compositing software like after effects, fusion or nuke.

Comment: Thank you vey much for your answer, I need it to be transparent, I'm gonna try adding the bloom effect with after effects...

Comment: your welcome ! and yes its the most proper way to do things in post production workflow, so you still have the flexibility to change the glow without needing to re-rendering everything.